# Less nesting not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

```css
.caseinfo {
    .make-md-column(12);
    background:#555;
    &p {
        background:#999 ;
    }
}
```

Why won't the nested paragraph change? I've also tried without the `&`

Comment: you should not use the `&` in this situation. Also notice that `&p` compiles into `.caseinfop` instead of `.caseinfo p`

Answer (score 0):

If I compile

```
@import "bootstrap.less";

.caseinfo {
    .make-md-column(12);
    background:#555 ;
        p {
            background:#999 ;
        }
}
```

the resulting css is

```
...
.caseinfo {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background: #555 ;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .caseinfo {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.caseinfo p {
  background: #999 ;
}
```

ie the .caseinfo div has a background colour of #555 and any paragraphs inside this div have a background colour of #999, and I confirmed this with a basic web page.  Maybe you could double check the paths in your less file.

Good luck!